# Android Drawable looks ugly due to scaling

Tags: android, image, size, drawable, dpi

I am writing a View that should show a drawable that seems to "never end".
It should be twice or third the displaysize and move slow through the display.

Therefore I studied some samplecode by Google and found the important Lines

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    canvasWidth = width;
    canvasHeight = height;
    float sf = backgroundImage.getWidth() / canvasWidth;
    backgroundImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(backgroundImage,
        (int) (canvasWidth * sf), canvasHeight, true);
    }
```

To rescale the image and than

```
        // decrement the far background
        backgroundXPos = backgroundXPos - DELTAMOVE;
        // calculate the wrap factor for matching image draw
        int newFarX = backgroundImage.getWidth() - (-backgroundXPos);
        // if we have scrolled all the way, reset to start
        if (newFarX <= 0) {
            backgroundXPos = 0;
            // only need one draw
            canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundImage, backgroundXPos, 0, null);

        } else {
            // need to draw original and wrap
            canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundImage, backgroundXPos, 0, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundImage, newFarX, 0, null);
        }
```

To draw the moving image. The images is already moving, it's fine.

But, and this is the point of my question, the image looks very ugly. Its original is 960*190 pixels by 240ppi. It should be drawn inside a view with 80dip of height and "fill_parent" width.

It should look same (and good) on all devices. I have tried a lot but I don't know how to make the picture look nice.

Thanks for your help.
Best regards,
Till

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're saying that it's a never ending drawable, probably you're writing a game of some sort. If your image is a [pixel-art type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_art), then you don't want any scaling; pixel-art-type images cannot be scaled and keep its crisp look (you can try using [nearest neighbor interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation) and scaling to an integer multiple of the original, which sometimes might work, but sometimes you will still need manual tweaks). This is the rare case where you actually would need to have different image resource for different screen resolutions.

Otherwise you might want to use a [vector image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics), but if -- as you said -- your original is a high resolution image, then vector image probably won't help much here.

btw, you probably want to show some screenshot. "Looks ugly" is just as helpful as saying my code does not work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for leaving no picture.
It is a pixel-art bitmap.

There is just the problem that I don't know, which size and resolution my image should have and which folder(drawable, drawable-hdpi, drawable-normal-mdpi and so on) it has to be in.
I already studied the pages of google talking about this topic but this gives me no clue.
The width of the image is the width of the screen, the height is set to 80dip.

Another question: why is this the 'rare case'?

Comment: @Till: because most of the time, you will usually use vector images or images that is smooth and so can be rescaled automatically. Pixel-art, on the other hand, usually requires manual tweaking to the rescaled image. Try disabling bilinear filtering (and so, using nearest-neighbor filter), and see if it works better in your case: `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(backgroundImage, (int) (canvasWidth * sf), canvasHeight, false);`. Make sure to resize only to an integer or a small fraction multiples of the original image (e.g. if original is 100x100, you can try 300x300, 200x200, 50x50, 25x25, 20x20)

Comment: @Till: try to play in Photoshop or GIMP or whatever your favorite image editor is, and try to find a setting which looks acceptable, and then try to reproduce this setting in Android (or just ships multiple bitmaps if you can't reproduce the setting in Android). Make sure to use nearest neighbor filtering or a specialized pixel-art rescale filter (e.g. scale2x), since you don't want the blurred edges that other rescale filters makes (those filters are useful for photos, where the blurred edges increases the "perceived" image resolution; in your case you want a clean, crisp edge)

Comment: @Lie Ryan Do you know which exact sizes/resolution is needed? Which folders in my android project do I need. there are lots of, like drawable, drawable-ldip, drawable-mdip, drawable-hdip, drawable-small-Xdpi, drawable-normal-Xdpi,and so on :-)

Comment: @Till: if Nearest Neighbor still does not look as good as you wanted it to, there are other more specialized algorithms available for pixel art scaling, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_art_scaling_algorithms

Comment: @Lie Ryan so is it the best to define the most specific folders in this case like drawable-normal-mdpi and so on? or is it mostly enough to use drawable-hdpi etc.?

Comment: @Till: whatever looks good enough for your needs compared to the effort of managing multiple images is the best for you. You need to decide for yourself.

Comment: @Lie Ryan Thanks for your comments. I'll try it out as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but instead of passing a null paint to your drawBitmap() calls, try making a paint with bitmap filtering disabled:

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setFilterBitmap(false);
canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundImage, backgroundXPos, 0, p);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your hint.Just tried it out and it looks like before.